# Monit appears to be working on command line but get 404 'There is no service by that name' in web interface

Tags: ubuntu, monit

Monit seems to be working, but when I go to the web interface at port :2812 I get

```
-->:/var/log$ sudo monit -t
Control file syntax OK
-->:/var/log$ sudo monit status
The Monit daemon 5.2.5 uptime: 11m 

System 'system_mydomain.net'
  status                            running
  monitoring status                 monitored
  load average                      [0.00] [0.01] [0.05]
  cpu                               0.0%us 0.0%sy 0.0%wa
  memory usage                      645520 kB [63.4%]
  swap usage                        213128 kB [10.1%]
  data collected                    Wed Feb 15 06:27:26 2012
```

Any ideas what would cause this?

Answer (score 3):

Probably your configuration is SSL enabled but you have not generated the private certificate for HTTPS.

If you do not care about security in your context, open `/etc/monit/monitrc` and replace the existing `httpd` section with

```
set httpd port 2812 and
   allow localhost
   allow admin:test
```

After a monit deamon restart, you should be able to connect to `http://localhost:2812/` with `admin` user and password `test`.

To allow access from anywhere, you have to use `allow 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0`

Please refer to [monit httpd documentation](http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#monit_httpd) section for full details.

If you want SSL enabled, you will have to generate a SSL self-signed certificate at /etc/certs/monit.pem thanks to the [following procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/serverguide/C/certificates-and-security.html), for instance.

Comment: I can't seem to access the web interface till I specify my external IP. Is there a way to allow the web interface to be available to all external IPs? Tried removing the 'allow localhost' condition, but it still didn't work.

Comment: According to documentation, you should use allow 0.0.0.0/32

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work. Just tried it again to double check. Only working when I hardcode my current IP.

Comment: @Abhic - did you ever get this working?  I'm getting the same problem.

Comment: @JonB Nope I didn't. Will be revisiting this sometime in 2 weeks. Will update this ticket then.

Comment: I can confirm what @Abhic mentions - I can only access monit externally when I specify the address of my remote system in the monit config

Comment: UPDATE: This line allows access for all external servers : allow 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get this working so that all external IPs could access the web interface.

In the end I used Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName monit.yourdomain.com
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:2812/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:2813/
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

You need the `proxy` and `proxy_http` mods enabled for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line 'allow localhost' from the configuration and restart monit